# Flutter: SingleChildScrollView shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In Scaffold I have a container to set background . in container's child I have `SingleChildScrollView` and in its child, I have `Column`. In children of this widget I have 2 `Expanded` widget :

```
Scaffold
    |
     Container
        |
         SingleChildScrollView
            |
             * Expanded
             * Expanded
```

This is code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
      body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("images/main_background.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(..)
                Expanded(..)
```

My problem is when on this page runs all the page has pink color means I got this error :

```
I/flutter ( 8893): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8893): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 8893): RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
I/flutter ( 8893): When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is
I/flutter ( 8893): in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a
I/flutter ( 8893): flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining
I/flutter ( 8893): space in the vertical direction.
I/flutter ( 8893): These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child
I/flutter ( 8893): cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
I/flutter ( 8893): Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible
I/flutter ( 8893): children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
I/flutter ( 8893): themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and
I/flutter ( 8893): then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
I/flutter ( 8893): constraints provided by the parent.
I/flutter ( 8893): If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using debugDumpRenderTree():
I/flutter ( 8893):   https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer
I/flutter ( 8893):   http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html
I/flutter ( 8893): The affected RenderFlex is:
I/flutter ( 8893):   RenderFlex#4b35c relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE(creator: Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#fcff2] ← Semantics ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#e245d] ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#471e6] ← ⋯, parentData: <none> (can use size), constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=320.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity), size: MISSING, direction: vertical, mainAxisAlignment: start, mainAxisSize: max, crossAxisAlignment: center, verticalDirection: down)
I/flutter ( 8893): The creator information is set to:
I/flutter ( 8893):   Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#fcff2] ← Semantics ← .....
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the two Expanded are expanding the Column and the SingleChildScrollView infinitely in the vertical axis. You have to constraint the height somewhere within the body.

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here, but the most straightforward solutions would be to either remove the two Expanded or the SingleChildScrollView.

You might also want to use a ListView instead of SingleChildScrollView + Column.

Answer (score 0):

- Expanded will expand based on the box constraints of the parent Column
- Looks like SingleChildScrollView is passing infinite height constraint to the Column and Expanded is trying to expand to infinite.

Try wrapping the Column with a Container or ConstrainedBox and pass finite height. To understand more, I have written an [article](https://medium.com/@sid.310/flutter-box-constraints-101-the-basics-bd0babe650f9) on why this might happen.